# What is the origin of $generalUtil in my atlassian-plugin.xml?

Tags: velocity, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm studying the code of a custom Confluence plugin, which contains an `atlassian-plugin.xml` file that includes references to two variables `$generalUtil` and `$helper`, but I find no definitions of them whatsoever in the entire project. They simply work and it appears to me that they are magically instantiated out of thin air.

```
<web-item key="configtab" name="configtab" section="system.space.tools/addons">
  <label key="myplugin.space.tools.addons.tab.label" />
  <link>/spaces/myplugin-config.action?spaceKey=$generalUtil.urlEncode($helper.spaceKey)</link>
</web-item>
```

The `$generalUtil` must be an instance of `com.atlassian.confluence.util.GeneralUtil`, which also has a method `urlEncode()`. But where does this variable originate from?

What puzzles me even more is the `$helper`, which has a `spaceKey` field/method that I find in the code, but without any relationship to any kind of Helper class. The `$helper` also appears in a velocity template, but also without any definition of it. Any ideas where this stuff is documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generalUtil` is documented here: https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/javadoc/7.11.6/

I think `helper` is https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/javadoc/7.11.6/com/atlassian/confluence/themes/GlobalHelper.html

They are injected into the Velocity context used to render that link.